# PHP Sessions, issue with printing session information

Tags: php, html, session, upload, echo

I've written a bit of code to upload a file to a server. When the file is successful I made my code go to another web page. On this web page I want to print the file properties which were gained from the previous page so I am using Sessions in PHP.

```
    //Starts up a new PHP session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['file']=$_FILES["file"];
    $_SESSION['name']=$_FILES['name'];
    $_SESSION['type']=$_FILES['type'];
    $_SESSION['size']=$_FILES['size'];
    $_SESSION['tmp_name']=$_FILES['tmp_name'];
```

That is my session on page1. Then, when the file is successful, I send the user to page2.

```
    header( 'Location: page2' ) ;
```

Now, on page2, I have this right at the top of my .php page:

```
    <?php
    //Starting session
    session_start();
    ?>
```

Then, further down for me to be able to print each variable out I've got:

```
    <?php
    Print_r ($_SESSION['file']);
    ?>
```

I get all my information all jumbled into a long sentence when this is done. I want to have control over the information and print it nice and neatly. What am I doing wrong? I've researched into loads of different ways of doing this and nothing has helped so far.

Tried that, also tried just printing SESSION, also tried echoing each one seperately with the words [Array] being printed only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you rid all of that assignments using something like `$_SESSION['uploaded_file'] = $_FILE`

Comment: Will that work the same/

Comment: try var_dump($_SESSION['file']); instead of print_r

Comment: My comment was just a general advise not strictly related to the answer at your problem. It looks ugly and more error prone to me :)

Comment: @Francesco thanks for the tip, I only started learning about PHP and sessions today if im being honest so i'm very new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two dimensional array like below

```
$_SESSION['upload1']['file']=$_FILES["file"];
$_SESSION['upload1']['name']=$_FILES['name'];
$_SESSION['upload1']['type']=$_FILES['type'];
$_SESSION['upload1']['size']=$_FILES['size'];
$_SESSION['upload1']['tmp_name']=$_FILES['tmp_name'];
```

on file2.php

```
   <?php

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION['upload1']);
    print "</pre>";

   ?>
```

Comment: Will try this now and see what happens. Thank you.

Comment: Did you start the session in file2.php?

Comment: <?php
//Starting session
session_start();
?>

Yep!

Comment: Yes you first start the session like <?php session_start(); ?>

Comment: Can you give me your first file1.php with html and php, i will check on my system and reply to you!

Comment: How can i go about doing that? I don't really want to show my whole file as I've worked hard to make this upload something...different. I can assure you I've put in everything correctly as you've written it. What is the best way of sharing this file with you so no-one else can go and view it?

Comment: ok no prob!.i will create a file1.php with one file upload field and in file2.php i will show the session info about the uploaded file.Is it ok for you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7046/discussion-between-sathishkumar-and-john-vasiliou)

Comment: i have finished waiting for your reply in chat room!

Comment: The files are in google docs https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QW7N-DC0AmMh9yzbt9s_DjsIhrZomjID7hCuFrDw4ZY/edit

Comment: Great guy, this person has helped me for the past 2 hours on chat with me giving me solutions. It turned to 1.21am in India where he is located and he has solved my solution. Cannot thank him enough, what a legend!

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with white-space breaks vs HTML breaks.

Just print it as [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) and you're good to go.

```
<pre>
<?= print_r ($_SESSION['file']); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: This might or might not be enough: If some part of $_SESSION contains '<' you are out of luck.

Comment: Array
        ([name] => 316483_180239712051619_129819073760350_377597_526239440_n.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpItSvpt
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 27632
)
1

Thanks for your help. The above is now my result. It looks a lot better, but a few questions. Why is there data that i have not requested in the Session? How do i remove the Array at the top and also why is there a 1 at the end? Any ideas anyone?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck actually it will render it perfectly... just test.

Comment: @John Vasiliou, that's probably for another question but in short, session carries a lot more information that the one you manually request. The 1 is the result of `true` returned from `print_r`

Comment: It works but not perfect, needs some tweaking please see comment above @Frankie

Comment: Thank you @Frankie. I shall do some of my own research on how to alter my results then. Thanks for the help. If I get stuck on trying to find the answer my self I'm sure someone here may help me in a new question :)

Comment: @John Vasiliou perfect! Now in SO (Stack Overflow) style you should upvote all the answers that were helpful and accept the answer that pinpointed your question (if any) by clicking on the "V" next to the answer. That will increase both your reputation and the reputation of the person answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

print_r() will print out your information in a nice ASCII-Art like format. The HTML engines render this unreadably. Chose "view source" (Ctl-U) in your browser to view it in a human-understandable form.

Comment: This wasn't what I'm looking for. This is for a social website for a retirement village, it needs to be graphically pleasing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install Xdebug which will make really nice formatting : http://xdebug.org/docs/install

and see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+install+xdebug if you have any issues installing xdebug

Answer (score 1):

Use a table to display the data (or am i missing something !?!) :

```
<table>
<tr><td>File Name</td><td><?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>File Size</td><td><?php echo $_SESSION['size'] ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

add whatever extra info you need ...